# RTL progress bar for Angular Material

Tags: angular-material

How do I change the direction of Angular Material progress bar for RTL languages?

There is a css translate function that needs to be hacked, but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

As an update, it appears this 'just works' in Material 7.3.6 using the 'dir' property.

```
<mat-progress-bar value="90" dir="rtl"></mat-progress-bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually override it via CSS using the following code:

```
::ng-deep .mat-progress-bar[dir='rtl'],
:host-context([dir='rtl']) ::ng-deep .mat-progress-bar {
  transform: none;
}
```

Once I find a better way I will inform you